# Getting wrong undistorted image with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I am new to computer vision and have been following some online tutorial for removing image distortion and camera calibration.

The program I wrote is as below.

```
# python imports
import cv2
import numpy as np
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s:%(message)s')

# Arrays to store the locations of points where two black squares intersect for the object and for the image.
objectpoints = []
imagepoints = []

# Prepare the points where the black squares intersect like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0)...... The third column denotes the z-coordinate of the point. So, it is always zero.

# 1. The first step is to create an array that will be correct shape to store the object coordinates. 
objp = np.zeros(shape=(6*8, 3), dtype=np.float32)

# 2. We will need to populate this array with correct coordinates. If you do not understand the math behind it, take a pen and paper and write it. It is easy. Just pay attention to the 
# type of the matrix formed by mgrid[] and the shape of the matrix. And print the final matrix to see how the result looks like at every operation on RHS. 
# These points indicate the points where the two black rectangeles touch on an actual (undistorted) chessboard. 
 
objp[:,:2]= np.mgrid[0:8, 0:6].T.reshape(-1, 2)

logging.info("Created object points for chessboard")

# Read any one image form the distorted images and convert it to gray-scale to feed it to the findChessboardCorners() in cv2.
img = cv2.imread(r"D:\Udacity course\Module2_camera\corner detection and camera calibration\calibration_test.png")
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)


found_corners, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(img_gray, (8,6), None)
logging.info("Found corners for input image")

# Append all the object points to objecpoints array and all image points to imagepoints array. (If the cv2.findChessboardCorners() is able to detect the corners in the image)
if found_corners == True:
    imagepoints.append(corners)
    objectpoints.append(objp)
    logging.info("loaded object points and image points to respective lists")

else:
    logging.error("No corners found in the image. Check the input image and the parameters for the image such as horizontal and vertical columns")

# In the following steps we will find the camera calibration matrix includig the distortion coefficient (dist), camera matrix (mtx), the radial and tangential skew vectors.
# It will also return the position of the camera in the world with values for rotation vector (rvec) and the translation vectors (tvecs)
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objectpoints, imagepoints, img.shape[::2], None, None)

logging.info("Found the camera matrix and the distortion coefficient from the image.")
logging.info("Camera matrix \n{}".format(mtx))
logging.info("distortion coefficient\n{}".format(dist))

# We can take in distortion image and return the undistorted image with the help of distortion coefficient and the camera matrix.
dst = cv2.undistort(img, mtx, dist, None, mtx)
cv2.imwrite('undistorted_img.png', dst)
cv2.imshow('undistorted image', dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The output image I am getting is not completely undistorted. It still seems distorted at the bottom. I am attaching the camera matrix and distortion coefficient I am getting below along with the distorted and un-distorted images.

Output:

```
2023-03-05 00:03:50,596:Created object points for chessboard
2023-03-05 00:03:50,642:Found corners for input image
2023-03-05 00:03:50,643:loaded object points and image points to respective lists
2023-03-05 00:03:50,650:Found the camera matrix and the distortion coefficient from the image.
2023-03-05 00:03:50,651:Camera matrix
[[1.05424776e+03 0.00000000e+00 5.76945956e+02]
 [0.00000000e+00 9.85451700e+02 7.42761812e+01]
 [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]]
2023-03-05 00:03:50,652:distortion coefficient
[[-0.390704   -1.37769503  0.19748877  0.03508645  1.58862494]]
```

Distorted Image:
[image]

Undistorted image:
[image]

Can someone please tell me what is wrong here? Is there some fundamental concept that I am failing to understand?

Comment: yes, the calibration is junk. please present calibration pictures.

Comment: This is the only picture I used. And how do you know calibration is going to hell? Is there any mathematical formula to check this sort of thing? Or can you recommend some good reading material for camera calibration?

Comment: Think about using multiple images.
Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74695673/