# Distortion coefficients vary wildly with each camera calibration test

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

Currently doing camera calibration with OpenCV checkerboard and encountered this issue. I've ran multiple camera calibration trials, each with the same camera BUT different sets of images. Each trial has about 15-22 images, each unique images. So, with every trial, i re-took a different set of images, in the same location, with slight variations in lighting conditions.

[example of one trial's images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOraD.png)

However, each trial's distortion coefficients vary wildly.

[excel comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2L9NC.png)

i've done up an excel file where i compare their values, as well as calculated the standard dev, variance and coefficient of variation. Values for focal length and optical center coordinates are fairly stable but otherwise for distortion coefficients.

Was expecting distortion coefficients to be within an acceptable range. But some of them have standard deviations much higher than their mean values. For example p1, has a coeffecient of variation of 717%. A CV percentage of 717% indicates that the standard deviation is over seven times larger than the mean. This suggests that there is substantial relative variability in my data. Why does it vary so much? And if this is normal, how do i know which trial's values to use?

This is my code for completion

```
"""
Based on https://learnopencv.com/camera-calibration-using-opencv
https://forum.dji.com/thread-206289-1-1.html

USAGE:
    1. Print the pattern at https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/doc/pattern.png
    2. Take a few pictures with the camera
    3. Save to INPUT_CALIBRATION_DIRECTORY/*.jpg
    4. Run `python calibrate_camera.jpg`, which generates a YAML file at OUTPUT_YAML_FILEPATH
    5. Save YAML file to `FLING.AI\\backend\\FAI_backend_API\\config`

"""
import cv2
import code
import numpy as np
import os
import sys
import glob
import pathlib
import oyaml as yaml  # To fix ordering; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121931
from collections import OrderedDict
import PIL.Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS
from PIL import ImageFile

ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = (
    True  # To avoid https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984426/
)

# Round to 3 digits and suppress scientific notation when printing numpy arrays
np.set_printoptions(precision=4, suppress=True)

OUTPUT_YAML_FILEPATH = r"C:\Users\Documents\camera_calibration\air2S\trial 5\air2S_trial_5.yaml"
INPUT_CALIBRATION_DIRECTORY = r"C:\Users\Documents\camera_calibration\air2S\trial 5"
SHOW_IMAGES = True

# Defining the dimensions of checkerboard
CHECKERBOARD = (6, 9)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

    # Creating vector to store vectors of 3D points for each checkerboard image
    objpoints = []
    # Creating vector to store vectors of 2D points for each checkerboard image
    imgpoints = []
    # A vector to store height and width of each image
    img_shapes = []
    # A vector for the camera make and model
    cam_types = []

    # Defining the world coordinates for 3D points
    objp = np.zeros((1, CHECKERBOARD[0] * CHECKERBOARD[1], 3), np.float32)
    objp[0, :, :2] = np.mgrid[0 : CHECKERBOARD[0], 0 : CHECKERBOARD[1]].T.reshape(-1, 2)

    # Extracting path of individual image stored in a given directory
    image_paths = [
        str(x)
        for x in pathlib.Path(INPUT_CALIBRATION_DIRECTORY).glob("**/*")
        if x.is_file() and pathlib.Path(x).suffix.upper() in [".PNG", ".JPG", ".JPEG"]
    ]
    if len(image_paths) == 0:
        print("No images to process.")
        sys.exit()

    for i, image_path in enumerate(image_paths):
        print(
            f"Image {i+1} of {len(image_paths)}: {pathlib.Path(image_path).stem}.",
            end="",
        )

        # "Open" the image to get the EXIF.  Luckily this is a lazy operation and
        # the image binary is not loaded here, so there is no big performance hit.
        pil_image = PIL.Image.open(image_path)
        # Note we can get these numbers 271, 272 from
        # [k for k in PIL.ExifTags.TAGS.keys() if PIL.ExifTags.TAGS[k] in ["Make", "Model"]]
        if not pil_image._getexif() is None:
            cam_types.append((pil_image._getexif()[271], pil_image._getexif()[272]))
        else:
            cam_types.append(("unknown", "unknown"))

        img = cv2.imread(image_path)
        if img is None:
            continue

        img_shapes.append(np.copy(img.shape[:2]))

        # If the current image is flipped 90 degrees relative to the first one, fix it
        if (
            len(img_shapes) > 1
            and img_shapes[-1][0] == img_shapes[0][1]
            and img_shapes[-1][1] == img_shapes[0][0]
            and img_shapes[-1][1] != img_shapes[-1][0]
        ):
            img = cv2.rotate(img, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
            img_shapes[-1] = [img_shapes[-1][1], img_shapes[-1][0]]
            print("rot img 90°", end="")

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        # Find the chess board corners
        # If the desired number of corners are found in the image then returns True with the corners
        is_chessboard_success, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(
            gray,
            CHECKERBOARD,
            cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH
            + cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK
            + cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE,
        )

        if not is_chessboard_success:
            print(" findChessboardCorners fail.")
            # Not successful so we won't use this image in camera calibration nor visualize it

        else:
            print(" findChessboardCorners done.", end="")
            # Refine the pixel coordinates for given 2d points
            corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)
            print("  cornerSubPix done.", end="")

            # Add the image and object points to for use  in camera calibration
            imgpoints.append(corners2)
            objpoints.append(objp)

            if SHOW_IMAGES:
                # Display the chessboard detection on the image!
                img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(
                    img, CHECKERBOARD, corners2, is_chessboard_success
                )
                print("  drawChessboardCorners done.")
                # Display a thumbnail
                thumb_size = (img.shape[1] // 6, img.shape[0] // 6)
                img_thumbnail = cv2.resize(
                    img, thumb_size, interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST
                )
                cv2.imshow("img", img_thumbnail)
                cv2.waitKey(700)  # wait 700 ms before moving on
            else:
                print()

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    # Check that all images have the same shape
    img_shapes = np.array(img_shapes)
    if not np.all(img_shapes == img_shapes[0, :]):
        raise AssertionError("Not all images are the same size:")
        print(img_shapes)

    height, width = img_shapes[0, :]

    cam_types = np.array(cam_types)
    if not np.all(cam_types == cam_types[0, :]):
        raise AssertionError("Not all images were taken by the same camera:")
        print(cam_types)

    """
    Perform camera calibration by passing the value of
        - known 3D points (objpoints) and
        - corresponding pixel coordinates of the detected corners (imgpoints)
    """
    ret, mtx, dist, _, _ = cv2.calibrateCamera(
        objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None
    )

    # rvecs = np.array(rvecs)
    # tvecs = np.array(tvecs)
    dist = list(dist[0])

    print("\nCamera matrix:\n", mtx)
    print("\nDistortion coefficients:\n", dist)
    # print("rvecs: \n\n", rvecs)
    # print("tvecs: \n\n", tvecs)

    # Summarize camera intrinsic data
    intrinsic_data = OrderedDict(
        [
            ("camera_make", str(cam_types[0][0])),
            ("camera_model", str(cam_types[0][1])),
            (
                "pinhole",
                OrderedDict(
                    [
                        ("fx", float(mtx[0, 0])),
                        ("fy", float(mtx[1, 1])),
                        ("cx", float(mtx[0, 2])),
                        ("cy", float(mtx[1, 2])),
                        ("width", int(width)),
                        ("height", int(height)),
                        ("skew", 0.0),
                    ]
                ),
            ),
            (
                "dist_coeffs",
                [
                    float(dist[0]),
                    float(dist[1]),
                    float(dist[2]),
                    float(dist[3]),
                    float(dist[4]),
                ],
            ),
            ("version", 0),
        ]
    )

    # Save camera intrinsic data to YAML file
    with open(OUTPUT_YAML_FILEPATH, "w") as outfile:
        yaml.dump(intrinsic_data, outfile, default_flow_style=False)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe, your "15-22 images" is not enough. ( Refer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74695673/ )

Comment: I think, looking change of each distortion coefficient independently is not meaningful. For example, {k1,k2 and k3} are coefficients of a radial distorion model function and not independent each other. So, you should compare function's curve shape rather than each value.

Comment: Does the final reprojection error also jump "strongly"?

Comment: It's not about "enough", it's about "good". There are guides on the net for good calibration data. Here: do not make the pattern directly face the camera. Make sure it fills a decent fraction of the view. Make sure you get plenty of points in the corners of the view. And the means of the DCs mean very little. They might be around 0. We're you gonna divide by zero?

Comment: Did you try to run OpenCV demo on your set of images and observe the same behavior? There you can find a copy-paste script that will run camera calibration.
https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html

Comment: thanks for the help guys. @fana how exactly can i compare the curve shape? like what should it be

Comment: the equations are detailed in opencv documentation. you would plot the equation's result given a varying x, hence varying r, while keeping y=0. or the other way around. the "master" equation contains every possible coefficient. simplify it. most coefficients, when equal to 0, just make some term of the equation be 0 or 1 itself (neutral).

Answer (score 0):

Camera calibration is, in essence, a data fitting problem. It is important to pick a model which has sufficient, but not too much flexibility to fit the given data. At the same time, data should be distributed over the entire domain in order to constraint the fit sufficiently.

In practical terms, this means:

- You do not have enough quality data to fit the rather complex default camera model with 5 distortion parameters reliably.
- k3 is only observed by wider angle lenses, and can most likely be fixed to zero for your camera. k2, p1, p2 likely are also not needed. Check if their inclusion actually lowers RPE by a significant amount and/or removes trends/bias in the residuals. You can plot residual magnitudes as a function of image radius to investigate this.
- Your sample data contains mostly observations from the image center. The higher order distortion parameters are barely observed at these pixel positions and hence not estimated well. A larger calibration target, and coded  patterns (ie. ChArUco) are recommended.

As pointed out by fana and Christoph Rackwitz in the comments, variation relative to the parameter is not meaningful when looking at the distortion coefficient (which might be close to zero). Instead you can plot the radial distortion function with different coefficients and compare them. In the range supported by evidence/observations, the polynomials likely are very similar.

Professional camera calibration software such as Calib.io Calibrator reports this resulting uncertainty in image space or in 3d for triangulation, which allows you to judge what the parameter uncertainties really mean in terms of accuracy: https://calib.io/products/calib I am affiliated to that company and have written an article on this topic here: https://calib.io/blogs/knowledge-base/understanding-parameter-uncertainty

Comment: there is someone who might be displeased with the best practices KB article, there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78137305/opencv-fish-eye-undistorting-issues-for-object-detection?noredirect=1#comment137765367_78137305