# OpenCV Fish Eye Undistorting Issues for Object Detection

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, fisheye

I am using a fish eye lens for object detection to maximize field of view (FOV). I have code to undistort the image but the reprojection error (2.9) is not great and the edges are really messed up. I have attached some of my code and an image of the undistortion. For calibration, I took a 8 by 11 checkerboard (7x10 inner corners) and took many images in each plane.

```
def calibrate(showPics=True):
    # Read Image
    root = os.getcwd()
    calibrationDir = os.path.join(root,'snapshots//')
    imgPathList = glob.glob(os.path.join(calibrationDir,'*.jpg'))

    # Initialize  
    nRows = 7 
    nCols = 10
    termCriteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER,30,0.001)
    worldPtsCur = np.zeros((nRows*nCols,3), np.float32)
    worldPtsCur[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:nRows,0:nCols].T.reshape(-1,2)
    worldPtsList = []
    imgPtsList = [] 

    # Find Corners 
    for curImgPath in imgPathList:
        imgBGR = cv.imread(curImgPath)
        imgGray = cv.cvtColor(imgBGR, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cornersFound, cornersOrg = cv.findChessboardCorners(imgGray,(nRows,nCols), None)

        if cornersFound == True:
            worldPtsList.append(worldPtsCur)
            cornersRefined = cv.cornerSubPix(imgGray,cornersOrg,(11,11),(-1,-1),termCriteria)
            imgPtsList.append(cornersRefined)

            if showPics: 
                cv.drawChessboardCorners(imgBGR,(nRows,nCols),cornersRefined,cornersFound)
                cv.imshow('Chessboard', imgBGR)
                cv.waitKey(500)
    cv.destroyAllWindows()

    # Calibrate 
    repError,camMatrix,distCoeff,rvecs,tvecs = cv.calibrateCamera(worldPtsList, imgPtsList, imgGray.shape[::-1],None,None)
    print('Camera Matrix:\n',camMatrix)
    print('distCoeff',distCoeff)
    print("Reproj Error (pixels): {:.4f}".format(repError))
 
    
    return camMatrix,distCoeff

def removeDistortion(camMatrix,distCoeff): 
    root = os.getcwd()
    imgPath = os.path.join(root,'snapshots//snapshot_20240310_153742.jpg')
    img = cv.imread(imgPath)
    
    height,width = img.shape[:2]
    camMatrixNew,roi = cv.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(camMatrix,distCoeff,(width,height),1,(width,height)) 
    imgUndist = cv.undistort(img,camMatrix,distCoeff,None,camMatrixNew)
```

[example of undistortion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qkixr.png)

Comment: If you crop the result image to the inner chessboard corners you see straight lines. But you also see that right out of that area a really bad distortion is present. To my knowledge this means that the camera is overfitting to the region where chessboard corners are present. Use much more images where the board is everywhere around the image area and if possible closer to the camera (covering more area in the image).

Comment: https://calib.io/blogs/knowledge-base/calibration-best-practices

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12821056/1435240 (the calib.io page is clearly plagiarized from it).

Comment: Using `cv.calibrateCamera` for fish eye lens is good way? OpenCV has implementations for fish eye camera model.